# How to set special key for all submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

**php (connect.php):-** This is working fine when i open it by its own url <"http://sunilcpr.tech/pages/hotel/connect.php">

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("shareddb-t.hosting.stackcp.net","hoteldetail-3133319f3d","sunil7117","hoteldetail-3133319f3d");
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die ("there is some problem");
}
?>
```

**php (entry.php):-** And this is working fine when i open it by its own url <"http://sunilcpr.tech/pages/hotel/entry.php">

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){
    print_r($_POST);
}
$query="SELECT * FROM entry";
if(mysqli_query($link,$query)){
    echo "Welcome to hotel";
}


?>
```

But when i want to try send my data from my form then i found some mistake which mention niche

**HTML** file for send data and in my file i have two submit button then i want a key for both button so that php can understand both of data and now when i clicked on submit button then my page is not sending any data for sever.

And this is my page please see it for source code: <"http://sunilcpr.tech/pages/hotel/entry.html">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an action to your php file in your `<form method="post">`

```
<form method="post" action = "entry.php">
```

I hope it helps and also prefer not to share your database credentials